# Uncaught Error: This component must be used inside a <RecoilRoot> component. - Single spa + Recoil

Tags: reactjs, single-spa

My goal is to export state from one microfrontend to another. The problem comes when there is use of recoil library in the component i get below error

Uncaught Error: This component must be used inside a  component.

Yes, I'm sure the main file in both microfrontends is wrapped in RecoilRoot

Here is example of code:

Microfrontend 1.

Recoil - Atom:

```js
export const testNumberState = atom<number>({
  key: 'testNumberState',
  default: 999,
});
```

Custom React Hook: (in folder hook)

```js
import { useRecoilValue } from 'recoil';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { testNumberState } from 'state/recoil';

const useTest = () => {
  const numberSubject = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  const recoilNumber = useRecoilValue(testNumberState);

  numberSubject.next(recoilNumber);

  const funFunction = () => console.log('fun', numberSubject.value);

  return {
    funFunction,
  };
};

export default useTest;
```

hook/index

```js
export { default as useTest } from './useTest';
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react';

import App from 'app';

const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: App,
  errorBoundary(err, info, props) {
    // Customize the root error boundary for your microfrontend here.
    return null;
  },
});

export const { bootstrap, mount, unmount } = lifecycles;

export * from './hooks/index';
```

Microfrontend 2.

declaration

```js
declare module "@microfrontend1" {
  export const useTest: () => {
    funFunction: () => void;
  };
}
```

In some component of microfrontend 2:

```js
import {
  useTest,
} from "@microfrontend1";
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const { funFunction } = useTest();
  
  funFunction();
  return (
    <p>Some Component</p>
  )
}

export default SomeComponent
```

So to sum up, I finally get an error that tells me that:
Uncaught Error: This component must be used inside a  component.

Do you know how this can be solved?

Or maybe the export of the file in which recoil is used is not feasible?